# How to create dynamic matrix 2d in java?

Tags: java, list, loops, matrix, arraylist

I want to create dynamic matrix 2d using loop in java. My code is

```
class Mat {
   public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        List<List<Integer>> group = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> single = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
            for (int j=0; j < 3; j++){
            single.add(i);
            }
            group.add(single);
        }
        group.remove(3);
        System.out.println(group);
   }
}
```

First question, how to create dynamic matrix 2D with loop? I want an output like [[0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2]] and the matrix value saved in the variable group.

Second question, after being saved in the variable group, how about if I want to remove list (number 3) in the variable? So, output is [[0,1,2], [0,1,2]].

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rest of your code creates a ***list*** `List<List<Integer>>` by changing

```
single.add(i);
```

to

```
single = new ArrayList<>(); // reset every iteration
for (int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
   single.add(j); // add 0,1,2
}
```

> how if i want remove list (number 3) in the variable?

```
group.remove(2); //removes the element at index 2
```